# How to retrieve data from Form in dynamically wizard in angular 6

Tags: angular, wizard

I'm trying to create dynamically form-wizard with `angular-archwizard` and I want to retrieve data from Form for each step as JSON when a user clicks on the finish button.
Hier is my code as an example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-step-wizard-pzxmco

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below for Sample code using angular-archwizard.

Also you can use some function like this to Get data :

```
getData(){
    this.wizard.wizardSteps._results.forEach(res=>{
      if(res.selected){
        console.log(res.stepTitle, res);
      }
    });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-archwizard-simple-demo-edsmgs?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: thanks, but as an example how can I read data from input tag?